Why doesn't the traditional method of drawing a tree diagram give me the right answer.
There are 5 blue and 6 purple counters in a bag. I pick one without viewing the colour and do not replace it. Then on the second pick, I get a purple. What is the probability that the third pick is a purple counter.
Bit stuck on this question, I tried drawing a probability tree and adding the two cases but it is giving me the wrong answer. The answer is 1/2.
Would appreciate an explanation.


Since you have not told us the details of your probability tree, we have no way to say where your mistake was. Please edit the question to show your work.

sorry about that i have added it now

Heuristically, you can swap the first two draws. Then the new second draw (the unknown one) takes place with a balanced bag, so the probability of drawing either color is $1/2$.

@BrianTung hey thank you, bit confused on what you mean by heuristically, and also why you can swap the first two draws. Also then, I dont understand why the second draw takes place with a balance bag.

You have calculated the probability that both the second and third picks are purple,
not conditioned on any other event.
If $A$ is the event that the second pick is purple and $B$ is the event that the third pick is purple, you have computed $P(A \cap B) = 3/11.$
The reason this is the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur is because you have only counted branches in your probability tree where both $A$ and $B$ occur.
But you want $P(B \mid A)$, the probability of $B$ given that $A$ occurs.
How do we know this?
It's a little subtle because the problem statement is not as explicit as it might have been, but it a reasonable interpretation to say that when a problem statement tells you that an event $A$ has happened and asks for the probability of $B$ (not "$A$ and $B$"), as this problem statement does,
that we're being asked for the conditional probability.
In other words, it's the fact that we're being asked about the probability of the third pick, knowing the result of the second pick, that makes this a conditional probability problem. It is also possible to ask about the probability of $B$, not conditioned on $A$ (that is, not using the information that $A$ occurs), which is written $P(B)$ and comes out to $5/11.$
You already know a formula that relates $P(A \cap B)$ to $P(B \mid A)$:
$$ P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}. $$
You should be able to see how to compute $P(A)$ from the probability tree you already made. It is a simpler calculation than $P(A \cap B)$ because when you are computing $P(A)$ you don't have to be concerned about whether $B$ occurred after $A$ did.

There is also an easier way to solve the problem.
The trick is to recognize that pulling three counters from a bag one at a time without replacement, while not even looking at the color of the first counter, is just a fancy way of choosing two counters one at a time.
So you can get the correct probability by ignoring the first counter completely and saying you pulled a purple counter "first" and now you want to know the probability that the "second" counter pulled is also purple.
This also involves conditional probability, but only in the same way that your probability tree involves conditional probability: you have $6/10$ on the second edge of the upper branch but $5/10$ on the second edge of the lower branch, which says that the probability of drawing a purple counter on the second draw given that you drew a blue counter on the first draw is $6/10$ whereas the probability of drawing a purple counter on the second draw given that you drew a purple counter on the first draw is $5/10.$
These are conditional probabilities whether or not you actually use the words "conditional probability."

Hi thanks for the reply, can you please explain how come we have to apply conditional probability on this tree, I have never come across using it on a probability tree without replacement, what sets this question apart?

also i tried again and i didnt get the answer, can you please send a worked solution if possible.
